# How to get sum of a column values based on a specific value in another column which exists in different row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is data **details**

```
 ID    NAME    STRVALUE INTVALUE
 1     d_n     d1         (null)
 2     d_n     d1         (null)
 3     d_n     d1         (null)
 3     u_n     u1         (null)
 3     s_l     4          4
 3     p_n     A          (null)
 4     d_n     d2         (null)
 5     d_n     d2         (null)
 6     d_n     d2         (null)
 6     u_n     u2         (null)
 6     s_l     5          5
 6     p_n     A          (null)
 7     d_n     d1         (null)
 8     d_n     d1         (null)
 9     d_n     d1         (null)
 9     u_n     u1         (null)
 9     s_l     5          5
 9     p_n     A          (null)
 10    d_n     d1         (null)
```

In my data, for each ID I have multiple rows. Each row has name, strvalue and intvalue.

Could someone please help me getting the output in the following format?

```
STRVALUE    INTVALUE_SUM
 d1          9
 d2          5
```

Query

```
SELECT 
  strvalue,
  SUM(intvalue) AS `Sum`
FROM
  d 
WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT 
    id 
  FROM
    e 
  WHERE TYPE = 'a_e' 
    AND USER = 1) 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried getting value but i am unable to sum it up

This is what I tried,

`select strvalue, Sum(intvalue) as Sum
from d 
where id in (select id 
               from e 
               where type='a_e' and user=1)
group by id`

Output I am getting  is this,

`STRVALUE SUM
 d1       4
 d2       5
 d1       5`

Comment: @Aaha Mysql or Sql Server ?

Comment: note: (select id from e where type='a_e' and user=1) returns the IDs I need correctly. this has no issues

Comment: @Khalid just to clarify, the query I tried was in mysql but I am looking for sql server query

Comment: You should do Group BY strvalue, instead of id. Or Group By id,strvalue if you need the group per id?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c87dd/8

Comment: @KiranHegde Group BY strvalue does not give what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the test data:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    STRVALUE VARCHAR(10),
    INTVALUE INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Test
(ID, NAME, STRVALUE, INTVALUE)
VALUES
(1,     'd_n',     'd1',         NULL),
(2,     'd_n',     'd1',         null),
(3,     'd_n',     'd1',         null),
(3,     'u_n',     'u1',         null),
(3,     's_l',     '4',          4),
(3,     'p_n',     'A',          null),
(4,     'd_n',     'd2',         null),
(5,     'd_n',     'd2',         null),
(6,     'd_n',     'd2',         null),
(6,     'u_n',     'u2',         null),
(6,     's_l',     '5',          5),
(6,     'p_n',     'A',          null),
(7,     'd_n',     'd1',         null),
(8,     'd_n',     'd1',         null),
(9,     'd_n',     'd1',         null),
(9,     'u_n',     'u1',         null),
(9,     's_l',     '5',          5),
(9,     'p_n',     'A',          null),
(10,    'd_n',     'd1',         null);
```

From the answer you are expecting, I guess that you are looking for the s_l rows matching the d_n ones and trying to get those values, here is the query.

```
SELECT d1.STRVALUE, SUM(d2.INTVALUE) AS INTVALUE_SUM FROM @Test d1
INNER JOIN @Test d2
    ON d1.ID = d2.ID
    AND d1.NAME = 'd_n'
    AND d2.NAME = 's_l'
GROUP BY D1.STRVALUE
```

Here is the output:

```
STRVALUE    INTVALUE_SUM
d1  9
d2  5
```

Now just fix up the query to pull the correct ids based on that other subquery you posted, and you should get your counts.